# Why does ES recommend to use single mapping per index and doesn't provide any "Join" functionality for this?

Tags: elasticsearch

As you know, starting from version **6**, ElasticSearch team deprecates multiple types per index as well as `parent-child` relationships. **Proof** is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

They recommend to use `join` queries instead of `parent-child`. But let's look on this `join` query [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html). They write:

> The join datatype is a special field that creates parent/child
>   relation within documents of the same index.

They offer to use multiple indexes, restrict their indexes to work with only 1 single mapping `_doc`, but `join` query is designed to work only in bounds of the same index.

How to live on? How could I create `parent-child` relationships for separate indexes?

Example:

```
Index: "City"
{
    "name": "Moscow",
    "id": 1
}

Index: "Product"
{
     "name": "Shirt",
     "city": 1,
     "id": 1
}

How could I get that "Shirt" above if I know only "Moscow" city name?
```